# How to apply images from the compositor to a model?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I know I can edit photos in the compositor, but can I apply the result of my edit to my current model? For example, I used the compositor to edit the headlight of a car. Can I apply this edit of the headlight to my model? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Load your image texture in the compositor, edit, and then save the result via Image Viewer and UV/Image Editor set to 'Image Viewer'. Load the saved image as a texture in the model's material and appropriate UV coordinates, etc. For now, there doesn't exist a definite link for live editing from the compositor to the material texture, but in the Cycles material node editor you CAN use color mix nodes and curve nodes, etc. to interactively edit some properties of the image texture.